# Can std::string_view created in function body be returned?

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose you have this code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::string_view foo(){
    char arr[3];
    arr[0]='0';
    arr[1]='1';
    arr[2]='\0';
    
    std::string_view sv = arr;
    return sv;
}

int main(){
    cout<<foo()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since `arr` is in the stack, during the creation of `sv`, sv should point to a location in the stack, therefore, since string_view doesn't copy the content of the internal char array (contrary on what happens on std::string), I would expect an error here, yet it prints correctly `01`.

Comment: The problem with *undefined behavior* is that it sometimes seems to work. If you save the value returned by `foo`, then call another function (with local variables) before you print the view, you would very likely get a very different behavior.

Comment: _Can std::string_view created in function body be returned?_ In general, yes.  It's an object, like any other.  _Is this code legal?_ No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least it's meaningless to return one<sup>*</sup>. You could do so, but a `std::string_view` relies on the underlying string representation it provides a view on. If that one has gone out of scope, any member access to the view that results in trying to access the underlying data (so nearly all – *maybe* size is stored separately, but it could be calculated from two iterators as well) invokes undefined behaviour and in consequence renders your programme invalid.

Undefined behaviour, though, can mean *anything* – sometimes you get away with, observing expected behaviour, sometimes you end up in a crash, sometimes you end up in heavy to debug and locate errors because of the error getting into effect much later at a seemingly totally unrelated place...

---

*<sub><sup>*</sup>Late edit for late readers: In given case, of course, as the string view would reference data with local storage duration; there are other scenarios where it is totally valid to return one, necessary precondition is that the data referred to has a life span at least as long as the string view still being used for accessing it…</sub>*